# How to assign text input to php valuables without submitting

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input, submit

Hi I am new to web developing. I am having a submit php page which is submitting datas from previous form page and also showing submit confirming info. But now I am going to make it asking users to enter 2 more things ( name and room number) before submitting to SQL, so... information from previous form and name, room number will be insert to SQL all together. I want to handle this submission within one same page, but for the new added 2 datas (name & room number) I don't want to do one separate submit() since I don't want the page refreshing,

How can I do it? How can I apply value from an input tag(Cname) to $Cname ? without refreshing the page ? Here is my code:

```
  ...

<head>
<?php

$T1comment1 = $_POST['T1comment1'];//these are from previous form
$T1comment2 = $_POST['T1comment2'];//these are from previous form
$T1comment3 = $_POST['T1comment3'];//these are from previous form
$T1comment4 = $_POST['T1comment4'];//these are from previous form

$item_1 = $_POST['item_1'];//these are from previous form
$item_2 = $_POST['item_2'];//these are from previous form
$item_3 = $_POST['item_3'];//these are from previous form
$item_4 = $_POST['item_4'];//these are from previous form

$Cname = $_POST['Cname'];
$CRnumber = $_POST['CRnumber'];


?>
</head>
<body>

 <div>

   <form method="POST" name="namdAndRm" id="namdAndRm"  action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>"  >


      <input type="text" id="Cname" name="Cname" value="your name here"></input>


      <input type="text" id="CRnumber" name="CRnumber" value="room no."></input>

   </form>

 </div>



<div>

    <div class="Back"></div>

    <div class="submit" onclick="goSubmit();"></div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function goSubmit(){
    <?php
$Cname = $_POST['Cname'];  //is this the right way to do it? 
$CRnumber = $_POST['CRnumber'];   // I tested a lot, seams direct "=" is not working...

$SqlStatement = "INSERT INTO T3survey (T1item_1, T1comment1, T1item_2, T1comment2, T1item_3, T1comment3, T1item_4, T1comment4, Cname, CRnumber, day) VALUES ('$item_1', '$T1comment1', '$item_2', '$T1comment2', '$item_3', '$T1comment3', '$item_4', '$T1comment4', '$Cname', '$CRnumber',  NOW())";
    $result = mysql_query($SqlStatement,$connection);
 if (!$result){ die("Error " . mysql_errno() . " : " . mysql_error());}
    ?>;
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `AJAX` to submit form without refresh

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create a bunch of hidden fields in your form, like so:

```
<input type='hidden' name ='T1comment1' value='<?php $T1comment1;?>'> 
<input type='hidden' name ='T1comment2' value='<?php $T1comment2;?>'> 
<input type='hidden' name ='T1comment3' value='<?php $T1comment3;?>'> 
<input type='hidden' name ='T1comment4' value='<?php $T1comment4;?>'>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, but what I am trying to do is in this same page input and submit Cname and CRnumber , I tried to do it with your way but nothing were assigned to $Cname and $ CRnumber

Comment: If $Cname and $CRnumber are empty you may have an issue in the prior page that submits the values. You can see what is being posted to the page to help you debug like this:

    <?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";
    ?>

Comment: Well actually I want to request input these 2 and also submit them in the same page, but without "submit" which might cause refreshing.  Thanks any way...